# Vue Router (History Mode) & Webpack External Redirect Handling

Tags: vue.js, redirect, webpack, vue-router, webpack-dev-server

SO Community,

I am working to add external authentication with an existing Vue 2 application. The issue I am facing is that after the external IdP redirects back to the Vue application with the path of `/redirect`, Vue Router does not appear to honor the updated path and route to the proper component. In other words, Vue Router routes to the `/` component rather than the `/redirect` component.

Vue Router does have `mode: 'history'` set and Webpack `historyApiFallback: true,` set.

## Current Behavior:

1. User navigates to `https://localhost:8080/` and renders a `Login` component.
2. User enters their ID and is redirected to the external IdP.
3. After successful authentication, the IdP returns to the specified redirect URL: `https://localhost:8080/redirect`
4. Because of history mode, Webpack sends the browser to `/` and thus back to the `Login` component.
5. In the `Login` component, the `mounted()` hook checks `if (window.location.pathname === '/redirect') router.push({ path: '/redirect' });`
6. Vue Router goes to the `/` path, rather than `/redirect` and its component.

### Technical Details:

Vue - 2.5.15
Vue Router - 3.0.0
Webpack - 4.17.1
Webpack Dev Server - 3.1.4

### `webpack.dev.js`

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
```

### `router.js`

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [

...

    {
      path: '/redirect',
      component: Redirect,
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: () => {

    },

...

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const user = store.state.user.authorizedUser
  const toPath = to.path

  if (toPath === '/redirect') return
});
```

### `App.vue`

```
new Vue({
  el: '#login',
  render: h => h(Login),
  store,
})
```

### `Login.vue`

```
mounted() {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/redirect') router.push({ path: '/redirect' });
}
```

Please let me know if I can provide any additional details or code. Thank you, in advance, for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue appeared to be with the top-level component `Login` acting as a traffic cop before the router kicked in. I had to edit the `Login` component to manually mount the `Redirect` component.

*I wouldn't advise this type of setup.*